# Default value for MergeLatest

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

The official [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mergeLatest.html) of `MergeLatest` states:

> MergeLatest emits list for each element emitted from some input stream, but only after each input stream emitted at least one element.

My question is: can this be bypassed? 
For example, can we provide a default value such that it will start producing lists as soon as it receives at least one element from any input stream?

The following should be the new behavior:

```
(1,0,0)
(2,0,0)
(2,1,0)
(2,1,1)
(2,1,2)
```

Instead of:

```
(2,1,1)
(2,1,2)
```

As I need those first lists to be pushed to the output stream as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `mergeLatest` doesn't provide such option.  And there doesn't seem to be any Stream operator that readily does that.  One way would be to repurpose [`MergeLatest`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.6.0/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/MergeLatest.scala) for the specific need.  Good news is that the necessary code change is rather simple as the relevant code implementation is a standard `GraphStage` of `UniformFanInShape`.

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.stage.{ GraphStage, GraphStageLogic, InHandler, OutHandler }
import akka.stream.{ Attributes, Inlet, Outlet, UniformFanInShape }
import scala.collection.immutable

object MergeLatestWithDefault {
  def apply[T](inputPorts: Int, default: T, eagerComplete: Boolean = false): GraphStage[UniformFanInShape[T, List[T]]] =
    new MergeLatestWithDefault[T, List[T]](inputPorts, default, eagerComplete)(_.toList)
}

final class MergeLatestWithDefault[T, M](val inputPorts: Int, val default: T, val eagerClose: Boolean)(buildElem: Array[T] => M)
    extends GraphStage[UniformFanInShape[T, M]] {
  require(inputPorts >= 1, "input ports must be >= 1")

  val in: immutable.IndexedSeq[Inlet[T]] = Vector.tabulate(inputPorts)(i => Inlet[T]("MergeLatestWithDefault.in" + i))
  val out: Outlet[M] = Outlet[M]("MergeLatestWithDefault.out")
  override val shape: UniformFanInShape[T, M] = UniformFanInShape(out, in: _*)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) with OutHandler {
      private val activeStreams: java.util.HashSet[Int] = new java.util.HashSet[Int]()
      private var runningUpstreams: Int = inputPorts
      private def upstreamsClosed: Boolean = runningUpstreams == 0
      private val messages: Array[Any] = Array.fill[Any](inputPorts)(default)

      override def preStart(): Unit = in.foreach(tryPull)

      in.zipWithIndex.foreach {
        case (input, index) =>
          setHandler(
            input,
            new InHandler {
              override def onPush(): Unit = {
                messages.update(index, grab(input))
                activeStreams.add(index)
                emit(out, buildElem(messages.asInstanceOf[Array[T]]))
                tryPull(input)
              }

              override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
                if (!eagerClose) {
                  runningUpstreams -= 1
                  if (upstreamsClosed) completeStage()
                } else completeStage()
              }
            })
      }

      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        var i = 0
        while (i < inputPorts) {
          if (!hasBeenPulled(in(i))) tryPull(in(i))
          i += 1
        }
      }

      setHandler(out, this)
    }

  override def toString = "MergeLatestWithDefault"
}
```

Only little code change is necessary in this case.  Besides an additional parameter for `default` to be filled in array `messages`, the only change is that `emit` within `onPush` is no longer conditional.

Testing it out:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object CustomMerge {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")

    val s1 = Source(1 to 3)
    val s2 = Source(11 to 13).throttle(1, 50.millis)
    val s3 = Source(101 to 103).throttle(1, 100.millis)

    Source.combine(s1, s2, s3)(MergeLatestWithDefault[Int](_, 0)).runForeach(println)
  }
}

// Output:
//
// List(1, 0, 0)
// List(1, 11, 0)
// List(1, 11, 101)
// List(2, 11, 101)
// List(2, 12, 101)
// List(3, 12, 101)
// List(3, 13, 101)
// List(3, 13, 102)
// List(3, 13, 103)
```

As a bonus, while `mergeLatest` is available only on Akka Stream `2.6`+, this repurposed code appears to work fine on `2.5` based on my brief testing.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the incoming streams, you could use `Source.single(0).concat` to emit a zero and then emit the rest of the stream:

```
def withInitialValue[A](source: Source[A, NotUsed], a: A): Source[A, NotUsed] =
  Source.single(a).concat(source)
```

Comment: This isn't the most elegant solution, but seems like it could work. Is it also possible to throw in the single zeros somewhere in the middle of the Flow? I currently have a source of something totally different than integers, so can't throw it in there. I would really have to add it to a Flow component (instead of a source component) just before it reaches my merge component in the GraphDSL.